# am chart labels are being chopped off

Tags: amcharts

I'm working on an am serial chart and am having a difficult time with the labels. If you look at my pen at http://codepen.io/drewtadams/pen/QKLYro, the last column's text is being cut off in the graph - I would like to move the text above the column, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. If this is a duplicate, I'd definitely appreciate a link to a solution.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://www.wgu.edu/sites/all/themes/bricktheme/javascripts/amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.wgu.edu/sites/all/themes/bricktheme/javascripts/amcharts/serial.js"></script>
<script src="amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="amcharts/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" class="bar-chart"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#chartdiv{
  height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

JS:

```
// info to be graphed
var chartData = [ {
    timeToGraduate: "1<br>Year",
    percent: 38,
    color: "#ffffff"
  }, {
    color: "#ffffff",
    percent: 29,
    timeToGraduate: "1.5<br>Years"
  }, {
    color: "#ffffff",
    percent: 19,
    timeToGraduate: "2<br>Years"
  }, {
    color: "#ffffff",
    percent: 9,
    timeToGraduate: "2.5<br>Years"
  }, {
    color: "#ffffff",
    percent: 3,
    timeToGraduate: "3<br>Years"
} ];


// chart properties
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
//chart.angle = 30;
chart.autoMargins = true;
chart.categoryAxis.labelsEnabled = false;
chart.categoryAxis.title = "Time to Graduate";
chart.categoryAxis.titleColor = "#406591";   
chart.categoryField = "timeToGraduate";
//chart.columnSpacing3D = 10;
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
//chart.depth3D = 25;
chart.handDrawn = false;
chart.type = "serial";


// graph properties
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.balloonText = "[[value]]%";
graph.fillAlphas = 1;
graph.labelColorField = "color";
graph.labelPosition = "bottom";
graph.labelText = "[[category]]";
graph.lineColor = "#406591";
graph.type = "column";
graph.urlField = "url";
graph.valueField = "percent";
chart.addGraph(graph);


// valueAxis properties
var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis.labelFrequency = 1;
valueAxis.minimum = 0;
valueAxis.title = "Percent of Grads";
valueAxis.titleColor = "#406591";
valueAxis.unit = "%";
chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis); // add valueAxis properties to chart


// draw out the graph
chart.write("chartdiv");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [labelOffset](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelOffset) property in AmGraph that allows you to shift graph labels by a pixel amount, however it will affect all labels, which may or may not be ideal. If you want to modify just that particular label, then you can  modify the SVG directly through the [drawn](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#drawn) event and set [addClassNames](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) to true in the chart object so you can query the SVG element directly:

```
chart.addClassNames = true;
chart.addListener("drawn", function(e) {
  var targetLabel = document.querySelectorAll('.amcharts-graph-label')[4]; // the last label contains the 3 Years string
  targetLabel.setAttribute("transform", "translate(226,204)"); //adjust the second value in translate to adjust the y position
});
```

[Codepen demo - modifying SVG](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/fbf74f5b3edb0c3fd8c57a3fc501c096?editors=0010)

You can find a list of class names available after setting `addClassNames` to true [here](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/css-class-names/).

If you're not comfortable with manually modifying the SVG, then you can display them as category axis labels instead.

[Codepen demo - using category axis labels](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/be7aa8de0ba8a82a1c08f3457765863a/?editors=0010)